# Marginal Distribution of Matrix Normal with Two Inverse Wisharts

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, wishart-distribution, random-matrix

Say I have a Matrix-Normal distribution and two Inverse Wishart Distributions

$$X \sim MN_{p\times n}(0, \Sigma, \Omega)$$
$$ \Sigma \sim IW(a, A) $$
$$ \Omega \sim IW(b, B)$$
where $a$ and $b$ are degrees of freedom and $A$ and $B$ are scale matrices.

I know that the marginal distribution of $p(X, \Omega)$ is matrix-T and given by $ T_{p\times n} (a, 0, A, \Omega)$. **What is the marginal distribution of $p(X)$?**

In other words, what is the marginal distribution when you marginalize over both inverse Wishart random variables? Is there a name for this distribution?

Comment: Did this end up having a nice posterior distribution? That is, is this conjugate?

Comment: I think this is not going to have a nice form because the Kronecker product of Inverse Wisharts is not a known distribution.

Comment: Agreed. I doubt its nice, but this remains an outstanding question. I don't have an answer yet.